# Bash script tee command syntax issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to echo the following line at the end of `~/.profile` file using tee command:

`export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`

To do this my bash script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
path_env="export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH""
echo $path_env| sudo tee -a  $HOME/.profile > /dev/null
```

But whenever I am executing the script it is also executing $PATH and $HOME value and inserts that in `~./profile` file which I do not want. I only want the exact line to be passed by the bash script instead of replacing $PATH and $HOME with its own values.

Comment: Why do use tee at all and not just a redirection of the echo output? It looks to me like you want to append it to your own user's .profile file? Then you also should not need the sudo command.
Just   echo "$path_evn" >> $HOME/.profile  should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want the exact line to be passed by the bash script instead of replacing $PATH and $HOME with its own values.

Och, right, so do not expand it. Quoting.

```
path_env='export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"'
echo "$path_env" | sudo tee -a "$HOME/.profile" > /dev/null
```